# ext3ファイルシステムにおいてディスクに書き込まれるタイミング・周期について

Tags: linux, c, filesystems

ext3ファイルシステムを組み込みLinuxで使用しています。
ジャーナリングモードはorderdモードを使用。
突然の電源遮断でファイルがディスク(CFを利用)に残らない現象を確認しており、Linuxの仕組みを調査しています。
私の認識が合っているのかご指摘をお願いします。

1. C言語でfopen->fwrite->fcloseの手順でファイルに書き込む(この時はまだメモリ上)
2. Linuxがext3に書き込む(30秒周期、この時はまだext3の一時ファイル？)
3. ext3がディスクにコミット(5秒周期、これでやっとディスクに残る)

2はLinuxのシステムコールsyncを呼ぶことで即座に行うことが可能。
しかし3があるので2が終わったあとでも書き込まれないこともある。

このような認識です。
また、2や3の周期は調整可能でしょうか？可能であれば設定方法も教えて頂けると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `3` について、man の `ext4(5)` にある `Mount options for ext3` には `commit=nrsec: Start a journal commit every nrsec seconds. The default value is 5 seconds.` と書かれています。

Comment: `2` については `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs` になります(`pdflush` スレッドの実行間隔)。今回の件では `vm.dirty_ratio` と `vm.dirty_background_ratio` を調整する(値を下げる)方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
参考になりました。頂いた情報を元に参考にしたページをリンクしておきます。
ext3のマウントオプション
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html
現在のマウントオプションの確認
http://www.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/HOME/kodama/tips-mount-optinos.html
Linuxシステム設定の意味
https://yomon.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/04/01/131732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

知りたい情報がmetropolis様のコメントで得られました。

#### ext3がディスクにコミット について

man の `ext4(5)` にある `Mount options for ext3` には `commit=nrsec: Start a journal commit every nrsec seconds. The default value is 5 seconds.` と書かれています。

#### Linuxがext3に書き込む について

`/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs` になります(`pdflush` スレッドの実行間隔)。今回の件では `vm.dirty_ratio` と `vm.dirty_background_ratio` を調整する(値を下げる)方が良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

なんだか XY 問題のような気もしなくはない

[ext3とトランザクション処理：Linuxファイルシステム技術解説（4） - ＠IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0309/17/news002_2.html)

で解説されているけどだいたいそんなもん（カーネル・デーモンバージョンが違うと違う動きをするかもしれない）

ディスク内容を壊したくない性能は落ちてもよいなら journal モードにするだけのような気がする（その手の実書き込みタイミングを気にしなくても済むはず = XY 問題かもしんまい）

CF ってことは NAND Flash が採用されているわけなんだけど、カード側ハードウエアによってウエアレベリングが実装されていないと PE サイクル超過で特定セクタだけぶっ壊れる＝製品寿命。 journal にするってことはメタデータ領域の書き込み回数が激増するので製品寿命に直結するからまずいかもしれない。なので journal / ordered のどっちが良いかってのはあなたなり上司なりの判断ってことになるっス。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
XY問題・・・確かにそうかもしれません。
根本的な問題は別のところにあります。
バイナリファイルをfwriteで一発で書き込んでいるはずが、最初の部分しか書き込まれていないという謎現象。

それ究明をする過程で自分の知識を補完しようと思った次第です。

問題はjournalモードで解決するのかもしれません。
懸念点の情報ありがとうございます。なかなかすんなり変更とはいかない話ですが、検討します。